# Hard Lefschetz for perverse sheaves on Kähler manifolds

Tags: kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory, perverse-sheaves

Let $(X,\omega)$ be a compact Kähler manifold, $k\ge0$, $P\in Perv(X)$ be a semisimple object, then do we have the hard Lefschetz isomorphism between perverse cohomology sheaves $\omega^k:{}^p\mathcal{H}^{-k}(P)\to {}^p\mathcal{H}^k(P)$?

A variant question is raised at the end of BBD (*Faisceaux pervers* by Beilinson, Berstein and Deligne). I don't know if the result is known now. The paper *Decomposition theorem for proper Kähler morphisms* [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/tohoku-mathematical-journal/volume-42/issue-2/Decomposition-theorem-for-proper-K%C3%A4hler-morphisms/10.2748/tmj/1178227650.full) by Saito seems to be closely related, but unfortunately I don't know polarizable Hodge modules much.